# Given an element and a list, how to functionally select the element after in the list?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'd like to understand how to solve this problem functionally (map/reduce/etc)

Say I have a list of objects (I'm working in javascript at the moment):

```
l = [ {id: 43}, {id: 64}, {id: 12} ]
```

and I want a function f that gives the next element in a list.

```
f(l, {id:64}) => {id:12})
```

and

```
f(l, {id:12}) => {id:43}
```

I understand how to solve this imperatively, but I am having a hard time seeing how to do this with map/reduce. Thank you!

Comment: Write a function that returns the index of the matching element, then add 1 to whatever it returns and use that as the index of the element to retrieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not accounting for things like element being the last item in the collection, or not being in the collection:

```
function findNext(collection, element) {
    var current = collection.indexOf(element);

    return collection[current + 1];
}
```

I don't see how reduce or map will make this any better. Unless you want to just pass in an id, and not an object from the collection. Then it's:

```
function findNext(collection, id) {
    var current = collection.map(function (e) { return e.id }).indexOf(id);

    return collection[current + 1];
}
```

First version, working in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cfxovfge/

Comment: Your function doesn't work on the example. It creates a *new* object to look for, so an indexOf will always return -1.

Comment: No, it does not. I have added a fiddle to show. JavaScript passes objects by reference, this does not create a new object.

Comment: Your jsfiddle differs from @jskulski example. You're using array elements, but the example uses `f(l, {id:64})`

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that that is a line of psuedocode. The question makes no sense if the input is an object that is not in the collection, but merely has the same keys and values as some other object in the collection.  And if that is what they want to do, my second function is the way to go.

Comment: Your second function does not exactly resolves the question: `f(l, {id:12})`. It's a good alternative, but we don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Read the title of the question, if the element is not in the list, you can't return the next element in the list, and the question is meaningless. You have misinterpreted what the input is.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
var arr = [ {id: 43}, {id: 64}, {id: 12} ] 

function findNext(arr, el) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(el);
    return index > 0 ? arr[(index + 1) % arr.length] : index;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(findNext(arr, arr[2])));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var f = function(arr, element) {
  for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (arr[i].id === element.id) {
      return arr[(i+1)%arr.length];
    }
  }
};
```

It returns undefined if it can't find the element.

*Edited*: Now it works, and it returns first if you ask for the next of the last element.